# Chrome-Extensions Jasmine Testing, Chrome,onMessage request methods not Identified

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, testing, google-chrome-extension, jasmine

So I've written a small chrome extension that gets my selection in chrome and adds it to a small textbox in a popup window.

For that Chrome Extension I want to write some small tests using Jasmine. However, whenever I try to test my Message `request.method` to be a set `request.method`, Jasmine always returns

> Error: Expected undefined to be 'get_sel_chrome.

This might seem very minor but I just cannot find the thing I am doing wrong.

Here are my Files:

```
//Jasmine Main Specification File

//Creating Suite
describe("Lacy-R Functionality Requirement Min Tests: ", function(){

//telling Jasmine to make sure that these are setup before each tests
beforeEach(function(){
      chrome = {
        extension: {
          onMessage: {
            addListener: function(request, sender, sendResponse){}
          }
        }
      }

});

 it('Check if Jasmine is loading. Just a small basic Jasmine test', function(){
     expect(1).toEqual(1);
    });


it('Checks if the request method is get_sel_chrome' , function(){
    expect(chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){request.method})).toBe("undefined");
});

it('Using Chrome API functions' , function(){

});
});
```

My main JS file:

```
//stuff chrome does
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){

    if (request.method = "get_sel_chrome"){

    sendResponse({data: window.getSelection().toString()});
}

    else{
    sendResponse({});} //empty response
});
```

Second File

```
$(function(){
  $('#btn_run').click(function(){get_Info();});
});

function get_Info() {
  chrome.tabs.query({active:true, windowId: chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT}, 

  function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab[0].id, {method: "get_sel_chrome"}, 

    function(response){
      var text = document.getElementById('text'); 
      text.innerHTML = response.data;

    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Could be because chrome.extension is deprecated for messaging, use chrome.runtime

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> if (request.method = "get_sel_chrome"){
> ```

This **sets** `request.method` to `get_sel_chrome`, which is probably not what you intended.

To avoid this in the future, see [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons) on why you should use `===` for comparison. [JSHint](https://github.com/jamesallardice/jslint-error-explanations/blob/master/message-articles/unexpected-assignment.md) should also catch this.